# Nginx (reverse proxy)+(web server) in the same domain

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm having problems setting nginx as a reverse proxy plus a web server, using the same hostname.

Using example.com, I can navigate my website, and if I go to example.com/rproxy I can reverse proxy to another dummy website: external.com What I want to do is being able to fully navigate both websites in just one domain.

But, I have problems when I use the links in the reverse proxy, as they don't get me where I want.

If I configure example.com as a reverse proxy, using this config:

```
 location / {
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass external.com/;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

Then it works. If I click a link that takes me into external.com/config, then the URL I'm seeing in the browser is example.com/config, but I can see that it's the content available at external.com/config.

All in all, I can navigate external.com fully.

But if I use this:

```
location /rproxy {
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass external.com/;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

There is no way to access the remote server folders. If I want to go to external.com/config, normally I click a config button and that takes me to example.com/rproxy/config, but the page is broken.

I've read some docs and can't find a solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was here:

https://serverfault.com/questions/932628/how-to-handle-relative-urls-correctly-with-a-nginx-reverse-proxy

The problem was fixed by using the easiest option: Changing all paths to relative paths with dots:
img src="/assets/image.png" -> img src="./assets/image.png"